# Characterzation of the complex numbers

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, field-theory, ordered-fields

There is a characterization of the real number system：complete ordered field. And the complete ordered field is unique up to isomorphism. I'm trying to charaterise the complex numbers in a similar way.

[In this paper](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/0025570X.1970.11976006), the author introduces the complex number system as a field $\mathbb{F}$ together with an automorphism $T:\mathbb{F}\rightarrow\mathbb{F}$ with certain properties ($T$ is intended to act as the complex conjugate operator) and a linear ordering on the subset $\{z\in\mathbb{F}:T(z)=z\}$ that turns it into a complete ordered field.

This method makes sense to me. However, I find it difficult to see why the introduction of the conjugate operator is a crucial step in defining a complex number system. And I came up with another method that seems plausible to me and I hope to receive some suggestions.

Definition: A complex number system $(C,+,\cdot,\lt)$ is a struture with the following postulates:

a)$(C,+,\cdot)$ is a field

b)there is a subset $R$ of $C$ such that $(R,+|_{R\times R},\cdot|_{R\times R},\lt)$ is a complete ordered field

c)there is an element $i\in C$ such that $i^2=-1$ ($1$ is the multiplicative identity)

d)for every $z\in C$, there is a unique $a\in R$ and a unique $b\in R$ such that $z=a+bi$ ($a$ is called the real part of $z$, denoted $\mathcal{Re(z)}$, and $b$ is called the imaginary part of $z$, denoted $\mathcal{Im(z)}$)

e)for every $z\in C$, $z\in R$ iff $\mathcal{Im(z)}=0$

Comment: Not sure if it helps, but as I recall, you can fully derive the field structure of $\mathbb C$ as a set of ordered pairs $(x,y), x,y\in \mathbb R$ with addition defined as $(x_1,y_1)+(x_2,y_2)=(x_1+x_2, y_1+y_2)$ and $(x_1,y_1)*(x_2,y_2)=(x_1x_2-y_1y_2, x_1y_2+x_2y_1)$. If the additive identity is $(0,0)$, and the multiplicative identity is $(1,0)$, one can use the axioms of a field to deduce the existence of $i=(0,1)$. I believe the conjugate follows naturally as the numerator of the multiplicative inverse having a rationalized denominator.

Comment: Your axiom (e) is a consequence of (d) and so is redundant.  Your approach works fine, although it's not clear that it's better than the characterization from the paper.

Comment: You could say more simply that $\mathbb{C}$ is the unique proper field extension of $\mathbb{R}$ of finite dimension over $\mathbb{R}$.